# Necesito guardar el resultado de mi consulta en un List para luego enviarlo a un xhtml

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

¿Cómo hago para mandar esos datos de dos tablas a un List y como los imprimo en el xhtml?

Lo que necesito es que me traiga estos datos Ej:

Tabla Usuario 
Nombre: juan 
IdCargo: 1

Tablas Cargo 
IdCargo: 1 
Nombre: Administrador

Resultado: Usuario.Nombre Cargo.Nombre --> juan Administrador

La consulta seria:

> SELECT Usuario.Nombre,Cargo.Nombre 
>   FROM Usuario inner join Cargo 
>   on Usuario.IdCargo= Cargo.IdCargo

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public List<Objeto> getUsuarios(){
    List Usuarios<Objeto> = new ArrayList<>();

    try 
    {
        Connection conexion=this.getConection();

        String Query="SELECT Usuario.IdUsuario,Usuario.Nombre,Cargo.Nombre FROM Usuario inner join Cargo on Usuario.IdCargo = cargo.IdCargo"; 
        Statement sentenciaSQL = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet cdr = sentenciaSQL.executeQuery(Query);

        while(cdr.next())
        {
            BeanUsuario dUsu = new BeanUsuario(); 
            dUsu.setIdUsuario(cdr.getInt("IdUsuario"));
            dUsu.setNombre(cdr.getString("Nombre")); 
            Usuarios.add(dUsu); 

            BeanCargo dCar = new BeanCargo(); 
            dCar.setNombre(cdr.getString("Nombre")); 
            Usuarios.add(dCar);
        }

        cdr.close();
        conexion.close(); 

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {

    } 
    finally
    {
        return Usuarios;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas se trata de relaciones entre Clases. Las relaciones entre clases y la forma en la que que se relacionan entre ellas.

Si quieres que acceder que junto a los datos del Usuario se muestren los del cargo es muy sencillo:

```
public class BeanUsuario{// Yo no la llamaría así dado que no sigue la denominacion Java Usuario es mejor nombre
  private int idUsuario; //Te recomiendo trabajar con long
  private String nombre;
  private BeanCargo cargo;

/*
constructores metodos y getters y setters.
*/
}

public class BeanCargo{//tambien te recomiendo cambiar de nombre
  private int idCargo;//lo mismo que lo anterior
  private String nombre;

/*
constructores metodos y getters y setters.
*/
}

   while(cdr.next())
        {
            BeanUsuario dUsu = new BeanUsuario(); 
            dUsu.setIdUsuario(cdr.getInt("IdUsuario"));
            dUsu.setNombre(cdr.getString("Nombre")); 
            usuarios.add(dUsu); //el nombre de los objetos siempre en minuscula

            BeanCargo dCar = new BeanCargo(); 
            dCar.setNombre(cdr.getString("Nombre")); 

            dUsu.setCargo(dCar);

             usuarios.add(dCar);
        }
```

De esta manera cuando quieras tendrás los datos de la clase BeanCargo. Por cierto te recomiendo devolver el codigo del cargo en la consulta dado que así abres la posibilidad de realizar acciones desde esa vista y no supone un incremento de recursos e implemnta de una manera más logica la Programación Orientada a Objetos y no la programación estructurada.

Las relaciones entre clases se pueden plasmar de muchas formas. En tu caso es la asociación.

Asociación: 
La relación entre clases conocida como Asociación, permite asociar objetos que colaboran entre si. Cabe destacar que no es una relación fuerte, es decir, el tiempo de vida de un objeto no depende del otro.

Ejemplo:

Un cliente puede tener asociadas muchas Ordenes de Compra, en cambio una orden de compra solo puede tener asociado un cliente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]